# Make my own basic shell

Tags: shell, prompt

I know there are a hundred ways of doing this, but I'm just asking what is the most common way:

How do I make my own terminal prompt? In other words, I want something like the shell where I type a command and it returns another prompt, but I don't want to be bound by the constraints of any existing shell's syntax.

I welcome answers using BASH, Perl, Ruby, Python, JS, or whatever... as long as it's bare-bones and fits in nicely with *nix conventions.

Comment: If you're looking to implement your own shell (as hinted by your comments below), have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788374/writing-a-basic-shell

Answer (score 2):

So you want to write a bare-bones shell (command interpreter). The minimal solution would be a loop that just reads a line, parses the command and its arguments, and executes it without any enhancements.

In python you could do it like this:

```
import os
while True:
    argv = raw_input("> ").split()
    os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT, argv[0], argv)
```

For example, you could run

```
> /bin/ls -l /etc
```

Next you'll probably want to add `PATH` look-up, so that you can just type `ls`. After that, the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you would set the `PS1` variable to create your own prompt.

For example:

```
$ export PS1="hello "
hello #your new prompt
```

See this for more ideas on setting fancy prompts: http://www.maketecheasier.com/8-useful-and-interesting-bash-prompts

Comment: This is not what I was asking. I'm asking about making my own CLI that is not bound by any shell syntax.

Comment: @themirror Did you mean a secondary prompt or a special prompt aka python or gnuplot? This page might give more insight for the latter: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs414/2004su/homework/shell/shell.html; for the former you can use PS2.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's not @ketan's fault that you don't know how to phrase your question properly. You want to know how to write a bare-bones shell (command interpreter).